# Why does calling cout.operator<<(const char*) print the address instead of the character string?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I was exploring the `ostream` class in C++. I am stuck on the strange output of `cout` on string and integer data types.

When passing an integer or floating-point value, the output is exactly what I pass. For example `cout.operator<<(10);` prints `10`. But when passing a string as an argument it is printing some hexadecimal values:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        const char* str = "aia";
        cout.operator<<(str);
        return 0;
}
```

Output: `0x4007e0`.

Comment: Why are you using `operator<<` directly like that? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @NicolBolas I suspect that they don't know what to do.

Comment: I am trying to understand how the cascading of operators actually works

Comment: Assuming you don't have some particular reason for using that form of operator<<, just use `cout << str;` and you'll see the output you expect.

Comment: Or you could try this `operator<<(out, str)`.

Comment: i tried and it prints the string but my question is why it is printing some hexa values when it can print same result for other data types

Comment: @john It's very valid and beneficial that OP found this weird behaviour when learning and asked a question about it. Not every question is a problem to be solved by a workaround, some are actually about understanding the issue at hand.

Comment: @TomášZato Completely agree, and I was wrong in my first comment where I assumed that they didn't know what they were doing. As you can see below I answered the question and did my best to explain what was happening.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When you do `cout.operator<<(str)` you call `cout`'s `operator <<` member function.  If we look at what [member functions overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) `cout` has we have

```
basic_ostream& operator<<( short value );
basic_ostream& operator<<( unsigned short value );

basic_ostream& operator<<( int value );
basic_ostream& operator<<( unsigned int value );

basic_ostream& operator<<( long value );
basic_ostream& operator<<( unsigned long value );

basic_ostream& operator<<( long long value );
basic_ostream& operator<<( unsigned long long value );

basic_ostream& operator<<( float value );
basic_ostream& operator<<( double value );
basic_ostream& operator<<( long double value );

basic_ostream& operator<<( bool value );

basic_ostream& operator<<( const void* value );

basic_ostream& operator<<( std::nullptr_t );

basic_ostream& operator<<( std::basic_streambuf<CharT, Traits>* sb);

basic_ostream& operator<<(
    std::ios_base& (*func)(std::ios_base&) );

basic_ostream& operator<<(
    std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>&) );

basic_ostream& operator<<(
    std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&) );
```

If you notice, there isn't one for a `const char*`, but there is one for a `const void*`.  So, your `const char*` is converted to a `const void*` and that version of the function prints the address held by the pointer.

What you need to do is call the [non member function overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) of `operator<<` and to do that you can use

```
cout << str;
```

Comment: Always use `cout << X`, never use `cout.operator<<(X)` or `operator<<(cout, X)` directly (unless you have a REALLY GOOD reason to do so).  Let the compiler decide which one to call based on context and data type.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've removed the `operator<<(cout, X)` call.  As you said, they should just use the operator syntax.

Answer (score 16):

The problem is that for some types `operator<<` is overloaded as a member of `ostream` and for some types it is overloaded as a global function. In the case of `const char*` it's a global function, so if you want to call the operator function explicitly you must write

```
operator<<(cout, str);
```

but for integer types you must write

```
cout.operator<<(num);
```

What's happening in the code you posted is that the overload for `const void*` is being called, which is why you see hexadecimal numbers.